# Huawei Mobile Partner crashes frequently in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, crash, usb-data-card

I am using Huawei Data card (E3131b model) in Windows 10 Pro 64bit. But everytime I run the software it crashes after a few minutes.

[image: Mobile_Partner_crash_message]

However the same software(which come with the datacard) was running without any problems in Windows 7 64bit system. I have reinstalled it multiple times and changed the compatibility mode to Windows 7 and Windows 8 and Always run as administrator. But that din't help either. What could be the problem? and How could I solve this?

Comment: Did you look for a WIndows 10 update for your software?

Comment: Yes, I tried [this firmware update](http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/?q=downloads) for E3131 now. But it's displaying "Finding port" and it also crashes. Is there any way I could run this without crashes? Or somewhere I could look for crash logs?

Comment: I meant an update for `Mobile Partner.exe` as well as any drivers/firmware. You might look in the [System Event Logs](http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-open-event-viewer-in-windows-10.html) for anything interesting around the time of the crash.

Comment: According to http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-broadband/dongles/tech-specs/e3131-en.htm the following are supported:

Windows XP SP3

Windows Vista SP1/SP2、Windows 7. Try contacting their support http://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobile-broadband/dongles/support/manuals/e3131-en.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally tried the following and it worked. Uninstalled the Mobile Partner software and restarted my system. Installed the Mobile Partner from the Data card and Installed the firmware update from the [Huawei Downloads](http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/?q=downloads) page and downloaded the [zip file for E3131](http://www.huaweidevice.co.in/Downloads/E3131.zip) and then installed the second `.exe` file which contains the text MAC. This `.exe` installed the updated new Mobile Partner Software.

***Note:***

*Disconnect and close the Mobile Partner while installing the second `.exe` file in the zip and also please don't remove the data card or do anything like put your computer to sleep/hibernate/shutdown etc..*